# Select one button from 3 buttons in react native

Tags: react-native

I have 3 buttons named **Pills**, **Syrup** and **Syringe**. User has to select one button from these 3 buttons. If user selects Syrup, then both syringe and pills has to be returned with false. This is similar to toggle button concept. Please share your ideas or any link for reference.

Below are my files for single toggle button.

**Priscription.js**

```
   <SelectDeselectButton
     iconName={'briefcase-medical'}
     iconFamily={"FontAwesome5"}
     iconBgColor={COLOR_WHITE}
     iconColor={COLOR_BLACK}
     selectedColor={COLOR_ORANGE}
     iconSize={30}
     initialSelection={isButtonSelected}
     onClickEvent={(item) => setIsButtonSelected(item)}
     />
```

**ToggleButton.js**

```
   import React, { useState } from 'react';
   import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native'
   import {  View, Button, Icon } from "native-base";

   //RESPONSIVE
   import { useScreenDimensions } from '../../ORIENTATION/useOrientation'
   import { normalize } from '../../ORIENTATION/FontScale'
   import { COLOR_WHITE } from '../Constants/Colors'
   const SelectDeselectButton = ({iconName, iconBgColor, iconColor, iconFamily, iconSize, 
   selectedColor, onClickEvent, initialSelection}) =>
   {
   const screenData = useScreenDimensions();
   const screenWidth = screenData.width;
   const screenHeight = screenData.height;

   const [isSelected, setIsSelected] = useState(initialSelection);
   const styles = StyleSheet.create({

   button:
   {
    width: screenWidth > screenHeight ? screenHeight / 4.5 : screenWidth / 3.5,
    height: screenWidth > screenHeight ? '50%' : '42%',
    backgroundColor: isSelected ? selectedColor : iconBgColor,
    shadowOpacity: 0.25,
    shadowRadius: 5,
    shadowColor: 'gray',
    shadowOffset: { height: 0, width: 0 },
    elevation: 1,
    justifyContent:'center',
    alignItems:'center'
   },
   icon:
   {
    fontSize:screenWidth > screenHeight ? normalize(iconSize) : normalize(iconSize+8),
    color: isSelected ? COLOR_WHITE : iconColor,
   }
   })

   const buttonHandler = () =>
   {
    setIsSelected(!isSelected);
    if(onClickEvent !== null)
    onClickEvent(isSelected);
   }

   return(
    <View>
       <Button rounded style={styles.button} onPress={() => buttonHandler()}>
            <Icon name={iconName} style={styles.icon} type={iconFamily}/>
      </Button>
    </View>
   )
   }


   export default SelectDeselectButton;
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of having `isSelected` as a boolean, set is as the button name as a string. Then you just need to compare to the button name to check if it selected.

**Toggle Button.js** // I changed the component for simplicity

```
const toggleButton = (type) => {
  const buttonHandler = () =>
   {
    setIsSelected(type);
    if(onClickEvent !== null)
    onClickEvent(isSelected);
   }

   return(
     <View>
       <Button rounded style={isSelected === type ? styles.activeButton : styles.button} onPress={() => buttonHandler()}>
            <Icon name={iconName} style={styles.icon} type={iconFamily}/>
      </Button>
    </View>
   )
   }
}
```

**Prescription.js**

```
import ToggleButton from './ToggleButton'

...
   const [isSelected, setIsSelected] = useState('');   
   <ToggleButton type = 'Syringe' isSelected = {isSelected} setIsSelected={setIsSelected}/>
   <ToggleButton type = 'Pill' isSelected = {isSelected} setIsSelected={setIsSelected}/>
   <ToggleButton type = 'Syrup' isSelected = {isSelected} setIsSelected={setIsSelected}/>
```

The reason I'm passing isSelected and the handler is because you're going to control the state in the parent component so that all buttons use the same state.